# Image hosting service for a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, image-uploading, mobile-application, imgur

I am making an app and want my users to be able to upload pictures.

I'd rather avoid implementing everything myself (eg an EC2 instance with custom code), but rather use a service with a decent API that would handle as much as possible on its side.

I see Imgur.com has an API that I could use. What else is out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageShack appear to have an API, whether it does what you want it to do is a different story...

http://api.imageshack.us/ :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I use [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com) to manage my App's backend services(including image/video hosting). Their free plan satisfies all my requirements